# Revmob - reconnecting to the server

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, revmob

I am developing a game and I decided to place my ads with Revmob(if you have a better company go ahead and share with, I tried admob but google is very strict and they banned my account for nothing so I am afraid my money will get locked).

Though the documentation for swift 3 is drastically poor I managed to display custom ads. Yet, I need help when reconnecting to the internet.

Here's the problem, whenever a user launches the app with no internet the ads won't display (of course), but then when the user reconnects to the internet during the same gameplay the ads still don't show.

My question: Is there a way to try to reconnect to the server every 15 seconds or so? And is it possible to display cached banner ads?

Thanks in advance!